# plugin of cakephp 3 is i18n not working

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

plugin of cakephp 3 is i18n not working.

I created po file.
plugin is Themes

```
Root\plugins\Example\src\Locale\ja_JP\example.po
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html

I am not good at English.
Regards.

Add code 01/03/2016

```
src\Controller\UsersController.php
public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->theme('Example');
}

plugins\Example\src\Template\Users\login.ctp
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Login')); ?>

plugins\Example\src\Locale\ja_JP\default.pot
#: Template/Users/login.ctp:8
msgid "Login"
msgstr "logged in"
```

But the display does not change. Error does not occur.

Comment: Please add code you have written so far and specify what error you get.

Comment: Hi thanks. add code regards.

Comment: i18n do not work in the plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting this

```
use Cake\I18n\Time;
```

Comment: Thanks. but not work.`plugins\Example\src\Locale\ja_JP\default.pot`is not work, but `src\Locale\ja_JP\default.po` is work. plugins Locale is not working.